# sklearn HalvingGridSearchCV giving inconsistent results

Tags: search, scikit-learn

The best params are not the same as the highest ranked. Here is the set up.

```
halving_cv = HalvingGridSearchCV(
    knn_model, knn_grid,
    scoring="roc_auc",
    n_jobs=-1,
    min_resources="exhaust",
    factor=3,
    cv=5, random_state=1234,
    refit=True,
)

grid_result = halving_cv.fit(x_trained, y_train)
```

And here are best params from it.

```
grid_result.best_params_  
{'algorithm': 'ball_tree', 'n_neighbors': 95, 'p': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'}
```

And here are top 4 ranked combos from `grid_result.cv_results_`:

```
    params  rank_test_score
{'algorithm': 'ball_tree', 'n_neighbors': 55, 'p': 2, 'weights': 'uniform'} 1
{'algorithm': 'ball_tree', 'n_neighbors': 55, 'p': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'} 2
{'algorithm': 'ball_tree', 'n_neighbors': 85, 'p': 2, 'weights': 'uniform'} 3
{'algorithm': 'ball_tree', 'n_neighbors': 15, 'p': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'} 4
```

The best params are not seen. The question is how `best_params_` is obtained?

I was expecting best params to be the highest ranked.

Answer (score 2):

With help of sklearn folks, I believe I have an answer. The table reflects the values as they are computed during halving. Hence, scores are based on sub-samples until the very last iteration. Hence, you might see high test scores on early iterations because of small sample size. It is the results from the last iteration (which uses the full table) that are actually reported as "best".